# "your grandfather’s and my health" or "your grandfather’s and mine health"?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, coordinating-conjunctions

> "Thank you, my dear, for always caring about your grandfather’s and my health.” my teary-eyed grandmother said turning her gaze towards me.

or

> "Thank you, my dear, for always caring about your grandfather’s and mine health.” my teary-eyed grandmother said turning her gaze towards me.

Comment: Your teary-eyed ***[what]***?

Comment: teary-eyed cat, perhaps.

Comment: In some areas, mine, thine and yourn appear to function as contractions of my own, thy own, and your own. So you can still hear "I can't believe mine sister did that" and "best be mindin' yourn bidness". As a form of emphasis, these are still current. As such "... grandfather's and my own health" works just fine. So the confusion isn't likely to go away anytime soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the first one (`and my health`), because `mine` sits in place of a noun (`It is not your toy -- it's mine!`) whereas `my` sits in place of an adjective (`This is a red car; it is my car.`)

Comment: Jdpipe is correct. The second version is just wrong. "... your grandfather's health and mine" would be a similar and correct construction.

Comment: @Anton It's not possible to know the meaning without more context. If *mine* is referring to *my grandfather* then that 2nd sentence would be almost OK (if a little clunky). It would mean "your grandfather's health and my grandfather's help", but would need to be realised as "your grandfather's and mine**'s** health".

Comment: Thank you for the help jdpipe, Anton and Araucaria. I will change it to " Your grandfather's health and mine."

Comment: By the way... on Phil Sweet's comment, a quote from Shakespeare: Before my God, I might not this believe
Without the sensible and true avouch
Of mine own eyes.